# Resolve DPI-scaling when embedding JavaFX within SWT FXCanvas

Tags: java, javafx, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse-RCP project where I need to use JavaFX controls and components within the SWT parts / windows. I include these controls in a simple part that wraps the JavaFX components within an `FXCanvas`. However, when I run the application on a computer with a high-DPI screen with font-scaling enabled, the contents of the `FXCanvas` render smaller (and blurrier) than those of the SWT part. Also notice that the JavaFX alert (which is on a pure-JavaFX stage and NOT within an FX-Canvas) is even smaller than the contents of the `FXCanvas`

[image: high-dpi screenshot]

For comparison, the same application run on a normal-DPI screen and no font-scaling looks as follows:

[image: normal-dpi screenshot]

My code for the `FXCanvasPart` is as follows:

```
public class FXCanvasPart {

    private FXCanvas fxCanvas;
    private Label label;
    private Button jfxButton;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(final Composite parent) {

        fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        label = new Label("This is an FX Label.");
        root.setTop(label);

        jfxButton = new Button("This is an FX button.");
        root.setCenter(jfxButton);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        fxCanvas.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

The SWT-part is equally simple:

```
public class SWTPart {

    private Label label;
    private Button button;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        label = new Label(parent, SWT.NULL);
        label.setText("This is an SWT text label.");

        button = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
        button.setText("This is an SWT button.");

    }
}
```

The JavaFX dialog is opened through a menu-item of the application using the following handler:

```
public class OpenDialogHandler {
    @Execute
    public void execute(Shell shell) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("A JavaFX dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText("Header text");
        alert.setContentText("This is a JavaFX Alert dialog.");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

I've uploaded a [zip file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wiFhW3gyvTmPfVjlbRXOoJgJudZk0v2o) with the complete Eclipse project demonstrating this problem if that makes it easier to look into this problem.

**Would anyone be able to clue me into what's going on and how to resolve this? Thanks!**

Both examples were run on using JDK 9.0.4 on Windows 10. Incidentally, when using JDK 8 on a machine with a high-DPI screen, the FXCanvas text is larger but the pure FX Dialog is correctly sized:

[image: high-DPI Java 8 screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191661

The fix is not likely until a couple of releases later.